# Big O of Recursive Methods

Tags: recursion, big-o

I'm having difficulty determining the big O of simple recursive methods. I can't wrap my head around what happens when a method is called multiple times.  I would be more specific about my areas of confusion, but at the moment I'm trying to answer some hw questions, and in lieu of not wanting to cheat, I ask that anyone responding to this post come up with a simple recursive method and provide a simple explanation of the big O of said method. (Preferably in Java... a language I'm learning.)

Thank you.

Comment: This really has little to do with recursion, and everything to do with big O notation.  If you can write it recursively, you can write it iteratively

Comment: @MStodd Not necessarily. Try traversing a binary tree iteratively.

Comment: @Drise You would need a stack, but it's possible.  Recursion just hides the stack inside the call stack.

Comment: @Drise maybe later.  The point is to help the OP refine their question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O notation using the recursion method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362452/big-o-notation-using-the-recursion-method)

Answer (score 34):

You can define the order recursively as well. For instance, let's say you have a function f. To calculate f(n) takes k steps. Now you want to calculate f(n+1). Lets say f(n+1) calls f(n) once, then f(n+1) takes k + some constant steps. Each invocation will take some constant steps extra, so this method is O(n).

Now look at another example. Lets say you implement fibonacci naively by adding the two previous results:

```
fib(n) = { return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) }
```

Now lets say you can calculate fib(n-2) and fib(n-1) both in about k steps. To calculate fib(n) you need k+k = 2*k steps. Now lets say you want to calculate fib(n+1). So you need twice as much steps as for fib(n-1). So this seems to be O(2^N)

Admittedly, this is not very formal, but hopefully this way you can get a bit of a feel.

Comment: A good way of conceptualizing this.  Again, would vote you up -- but I'm not at 15 points yet.

Comment: Adding a useful link here : https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1176/handouts/midterm/5-BigO.pdf

Answer (score 17):

You might want to refer to the master theorem for finding the big O of recursive methods. Here is the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

You want to think of a recursive problem like a tree. Then, consider each level of the tree and the amount of work required. Problems will generally fall into 3 categories, root heavy (first iteration >> rest of tree), balanced (each level has equal amounts of work), leaf heavy (last iteration >> rest of tree).

Taking merge sort as an example:

```
define mergeSort(list toSort):
    if(length of toSort <= 1):
        return toSort
    list left = toSort from [0, length of toSort/2)
    list right = toSort from [length of toSort/2, length of toSort)
    merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
```

You can see that each call of mergeSort in turn calls 2 more mergeSorts of 1/2 the original length. We know that the merge procedure will take time proportional to the number of values being merged.

The recurrence relationship is then T(n) = 2*T(n/2)+O(n). The two comes from the 2 calls and the n/2 is from each call having only half the number of elements. However, at each level there are the same number of elements n which need to be merged, so the constant work at each level is O(n).

We know the work is evenly distributed (O(n) each depth) and the tree is log_2(n) deep, so the big O of the recursive function is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: I would vote you up, but my reputation isn't high enough.  This does help.  I'll focus on the master theorem. Thanks.

Comment: @user1333461 If this was helpful, please accpet his answer.