# Big O notation using the recursion method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

How to find the Big O for the following recursive function using the recursive method:

```
T(n)=(n-1)T(n-1)+(n-1)T(n-2)
```

Comment: It depends on implementation of this function (will you avoid duplicated calls for the same input values or will not?).

Comment: Generating functions should be handy to solve this case, I believe. You've got to provide base cases though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I tried to solve this case using the classic recursive relation methodology.
It's all about observing if a pattern exists:

[image]

Very expensive algorithm (Enemies of computer science are factorial and exponential orders of growth).