# How do I find the space and time complexities for this code

Tags: big-o, sml

```
fun root(n) =
if n>0 then
let
  val x = root(n div 4);
in
  if (2*x+1)*(2*x+1) > n then 2*x
  else 2*x+1
end
else 0;

fun isPrime(n,c) =
if c<=root(n) then
  if n mod c = 0 then false
  else isPrime(n,c+1)
else true;
```

The time complexity for the root(n) function here is O(log(n)): the number is getting divided by 4 at every step and the code in the function itself is O(1). The time complexity for the isPrime function is o(sqrt(n)) as it runs iteratively from 1 to sqrt(n). The issue I face now is what would be the order of both functions together? Would it just be O(sqrt(n)) or would it be O(sqrt(n)*log(n)) or something else altogether?

I'm new to big O notation in general, I have gone through multiple websites and youtube videos trying to understand the concept but I can't seem to calculate it with any confidence... If you guys could point me towards a few resources to help me practice calculating, it would be a great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O of Recursive Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750226/big-o-of-recursive-methods)

Comment: @SimonShine yes thank you, I'll have to spend a little more time understanding the master theorem which on first glance looks very helpful... Could you just confirm what the order would be for the code I posted though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root(n)` is *O(log₄(n))*, yes.

`isPrime(n,c)` is *O((√n - c) · log₄(n))*:

- You recompute `root(n)` in every step even though it never changes, causing the "*... · log₄(n)*".
- You iterate `c` from some value up to `root(n)`; while it is upwards bounded by `root(n)`, it is not downards bounded: `c` could start at 0, or at an arbitrarily large negative number, or at a positive number less than or equal to *√n*, or at a number greater than *√n*. If you assume that `c` starts at 0, then `isPrime(n,c)` is *O(√n · log₄(n))*.

You probably want to prove this using either induction or by reference to the Master Theorem. You may want to simplify `isPrime` so that it does not take `c` as an argument in its outer signature, and so that it does not recompute `root(n)` unnecessarily on every iteration.

For example:

```
fun isPrime n =
    let
      val sq = root n
      fun check c = c > sq orelse (n mod c <> 0 andalso check (c + 1))
    in
      check 2
    end
```

This `isPrime(n)` is *O(√n + log₄(n))*, or just *O(√n)* if we omit lower-order terms.

First it computes `root n` *once* at *O(log₄(n))*.

Then it loops from 0 up to `root n` *once* at *O(√n)*.

Note that neither of us have proven anything formally at this point.

*(**Edit:** Changed `check (n, 0)` to `check (n, 2)`, since duh.)*

*(**Edit:** Removed `n` as argument from `check` since it never varies.)*

*(**Edit:** As you point out, Aryan, looping from 2 to `root n` is indeed *O(√n)* even though computing `root n` takes only *O(log₄(n))*!)*

Comment: I left the c as is because I actually use this as a helper function in a bigger algorithm. I really like your implementation of the check though thank you for that. What I dont understand is that while in my isPrime function I am iterating from 2 to root(n) (I initialise c to 2) so shouldnt that take O(root(n)) time?

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you could make use of checking from some point and up. Smart. :-) I was only thinking of pros/cons for proving and generally keeping interfaces minimal. To answer your question: Yes, it *should*. But you call `root(n)` once in each iteration. This is comparable to the C code `for (int i = 0; i < expensiveOperation(); i++)` vs. `for (int i = 0, max = expensiveOperation(); i < max; i++)`.

Comment: Right I see. But still in the code which you have, the loop from 0 to root(n) should take O(root(n)) complexity shouldnt it?

Comment: Does my answer somehow disagree with that? (I fixed the 0 into a 2, that was a mistake on my side.) If "`root(n)` is *O(log₄(n))*", then shouldn't a function that calls `root(n)` also have a term in its time complexity that is also *O(log₄(n))*? I'm not sure if your questions are directed towards the wording of "root(n)" vs. "log₄(n)".

Comment: Sorry this seems to be a misunderstanding... Your isPrime function should have an order of O(√n) shouldn't it? Because it iterates from 2 to √n? According to what I've studied till now the O(log n) can be ignored because √n > log n...

Comment: That is totally correct, I am being a dimwit. :-) I fixed this now. And yes, you can leave out lower-order terms easily by stating the definition of *O(...)* and picking a larger constant after which the higher-order term will forever dominate the lower-order term(s). While this is true asymptotically, it may also be a little opaque: It may not change anything asymptotically whether you recurse a data structure fully one or three times, but in practice for large enough data structures, constant multiples certainly do matter.

Comment: Alrighty! I think I understand this far better now. Thank you so much for the help!